# invalid token with hex()

Tags: python-3.x, binary, hex

I have a set of binary number, some of them start with 0, for example:

```
000000000001
```

When I use `hex(000000000001)` I get the following error:

```
>>> hex(0000000000000001)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    hex(0000000000000001)
                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid token
```

But I dont have with :

```
>>> hex(0000000000000000)
'0x0'
```

How to pass some digit if they start with zero?

Comment: leading zeros in integers (except for `0` itself and the prefixes `0x`, `0o` and `0b` of course) are a syntax error in python 3. see [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#integer-literals).

Comment: @hiroprotagonist , But I didn't get error with 000000000000, I didn't use `0b`

Comment: `0` itself works. as the doc states: *Note that leading zeros in a non-zero decimal number are not allowed.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do the following steps:

```
string_of_bits = '0b' + '000000000001' 
hex(int(string_of_bits,2))
```